# p256 signature in iOS Swift is 70 or 71 bytes instead of 64 bytes in Rust

Tags: swift, rust, ecdsa, secp256k1, ecdsasignature

I have the following Swift code to generate a random key and then sign a message:

```
let privateKeyAttributes = [
  kSecAttrIsPermanent as String    : true
  ] as [String : Any]

let attributes: [String: Any] = [
  kSecAttrKeyType as String       : kSecAttrKeyTypeECSECPrimeRandom,
  kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String : 256,
  kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String   : privateKeyAttributes
]

var error1: Unmanaged<CFError>?

guard let privateKey = SecKeyCreateRandomKey(attributes as CFDictionary, &error1) else {
    print(error1!.takeRetainedValue() as Error)
    return
}

var error2: Unmanaged<CFError>?
let message = "Hello"
guard let msgData = message.data(using: .utf8), let signature = SecKeyCreateSignature(privateKey, .ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256, msgData as CFData, &error2) as? Data else {
    print(error1!.takeRetainedValue() as Error)
    return
}

print(signature.count) //sometimes 70, sometimes 71 bytes

print(signature as NSData) //{length = 71, bytes = 0x30450220 0795c7a8 c9c34ba3 732966fb ... 720cad1c 7dc2a173 }

print(signature.hexadecimal) //304502200795c7a8c9c34ba3732966fb24d5bffc01d8d28d81182422559e9a6858b79a520221008c0fed0edcd338881e643ce4a810e4318a83f8f8c1d25657720cad1c7dc2a173
```

The problem is that when I so something similar in Rust using P256, my signature there is 64 bytes. Whereas in swift, it's sometimes 70 bytes, sometimes 71 bytes.

Here's similar in Rust using the example in [this link](https://docs.rs/p256/latest/p256/ecdsa/index.html):

```
let signing_key = SigningKey::random(&mut OsRng);
let message = b"Hello";
let signature: Signature = signing_key.sign(message);

println!("signature: {}, {:?}",signature.to_bytes().len(),hex::encode(signature.to_bytes()));// prints: signature: 64, "08f7ecf7c4c4f5142ef35e3ca294726fae48675c817a9d46e11e86cb60dd459fca8e580f44fb6a5c9b4b85107c161b2508fc1e198a12f06f3d960e45e4a19559"
```

Because of this difference, the Swift generated signature doesn't turn into a valid signature in my Rust backend. Why's Swift different?

**EDIT:** Another thing I have just noticed is that if I change the swift code from `.ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256` to `.ecdsaSignatureMessageRFC4754SHA256`, then it generates a 64 bytes signature. However, that's only available in iOS 17 onwards:

```
'ecdsaSignatureMessageRFC4754SHA256' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer
```

What's the difference between `ecdsaSignatureMessageX962SHA256` and  `ecdsaSignatureMessageRFC4754SHA256`?

Comment: Your ECDSA signature seems to have the ASN.1/DER format, while you need the IEEE P1363 format, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57731).

Comment: Note RFC4754 section 7 clearly describes its format -- concatenation of r,s encoded as fixed length (implicitly unsigned, because they don't leave room for a sign bit) -- although it doesn't describe how this differs from ASN.1/DER. In addition to P1363 and IKE this format is used by PKCS11 and some (other) smartcard interfaces, xmldsig and JOSE/JWS -- and _sometimes_(!) Bitcoin.

Comment: is there any built in or easy way to convert it to IEEE P1363 format in swift? (not sure if this is a dumb question or not)

Comment: If you can't find a Swift library, you can implement it yourself. The link above describes the difference between the two formats (as you can see, r and s are embedded in the ASN.1/DER formatted signature). The most convenient way to extract r and s is probably with an ASN.1 parser. When concatenating, make sure that both parts for P-256 are 32 bytes each (i.e. if longer, remove the leading 0x00, if shorter, pad from the front with 0x00 values).